# File input in bash script from an array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, bash, unix, terminal

Given an array of strings, I need to input each of these strings as a source file into a build script.

1. Declare the array (the extra space at the end of the filename is deliberate):

```bash
SOURCES=( \
"../../header1.h " \
"../../source1.cpp " \
"../../header2.h " \
"../../header3.h " \
...
"./main.cpp")
```

2. Convert contents of array into one string:

```bash
SOURCE_AS_STR=""
for val in "${SOURCES[@]}";
do
    SOURCE_AS_STR+=$val
done
```

3. Redirect string into a build script:

```
bash my_build_script.sh < "${SOURCE_AS_STR}"
```

BASH terminal response: `... No such file or directory`

I've tried arrays and heredoc strings but I am getting "ambiguous redirect" error as well.

Comment: Well surely `...` shouldn't be in the array should it?

Comment: Anyway you can use `bash my_build_script.sh "${SOURCES[@]}"`

Comment: If you want the string to go to the stdin of the command, use a "here string": `<<<`.

Comment: You don't need those backslash characters in the array declaration. Newlines don't end a `=(...)` variable assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes (when defining `SOURCES`) are unnecessary, but they don't harm.

In your approach, you are telling bash to use the string stored in `SOURCE_AS_A_STRING` as filename and feed the content of this file into the standard input of the script.

You did not specify, how `my_build_script.sh` expects the input, so here are various possibilities:

- If the input is to be processed via stdin, do a

  `my_build_script.sh <<<$SOURCE_AS_A_STRING`
- If the input should be passed to the script as a parameter, do a

  `my_build_script.sh "$SOURCE_AS_A_STRING"`
- If the input should be passed to the script via the environment (say, via the environment variable `BUILD_INPUT`), do a

  `BUILD_INPUT=$SOURCE_AS_A_STRING my_build_script.sh`

Of course the question is why your scripts expects an input (in whatever way) as a single string, and not as list of file names. This smells like a badly designed script file.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to lose the redirect `<` and I could do `bash my_build_script.sh "${SOURCES[@]}"` as suggested in comments by Paolo.

My problem was the "redirect was ambiguous", so I didn't know I could just drop the `<` and send the array.